# Should i create a view ( consisting UIButton, UILabel etc) in a separate UIView class or inside UIViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, separation-of-concerns, architectural-patterns

I have a `UIViewController` say viewControllerA which contains some view element like `UIButton`, `UILabel` etc. Now my question is should I create those view elements in a separate `UIView` class and then add in `UIViewController`, or should I create those view elements directly inside the `UIViewController`. Accordingly to MVC isn't it appropriate to create view elements inside a separate `UIView` class and then add this in `UIViewController`?

Comment: this is purely depends upon your requirement

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not creating these Buttons and labels in storyboard in xcode and then linking them to your VC class for actions and outlets?

Comment: @manujmv But accordingly MVC isn't it appropriate to have all the view elements in a separate class?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 infact i want to do it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

The standard place to build the view hierarchy in a UIViewController is in the `-viewDidLoad` method. That method gets called whenever the UIViewController's view is created. The view controller's view will be loaded from the NIB/Storyboard if applicable; your outlets will be wired up; and then `-viewDidLoad` is called for you to perform further customization:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,100.0,40.0)];
    [self.view addSubView:aLabel];
}
```

In Cocoa/Cocoa Touch you don't always want to subclass everything the way you would in, say, Java. There are often other preferred means of extending the functionality in built-in classes such as Objective-C categories, delegation, and pre-defined properties.

It's certainly possible to do this sort of thing another way, but this is the most "Cocoa-like" way to do it. Actually, the most "Cocoa-like" way would be to create the view hierarchy in Interface Builder, but if you want to do it programmatically this is the usual way.